# Continuous functions on the Sorgenfrey line

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I need to check if the function $f:\mathbb R_{s} \to\mathbb R_{s}$, $f(x) = -x$ is continuous when $\mathbb R_{s}$ is the Sorgenfrey line.

The interval $[a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb R_{s}$ but $f^{-1}([a,b))=(-b,-a]$ which is not open. So I conclude that f is not continuous.

But I saw a theorem that says: non constant function $\mathbb R_{s} \to \mathbb R_{s}$ is continuous iff the preimage of every element is finite, and if we take $y \in\mathbb R_{s}$ we have $f^{-1}(\{y\})=\{-y\}$ and this is finite so f is continuous.

What am I missing?

edit: I see now that I read the theorem wrong the theorem talking about function $\mathbb R_{CF} \to\mathbb R_{CF}$ when $\mathbb R_{CF}$ is the co-finite topology on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct (that is, if you know how to prove that $(-b,-a]$ is not an open set).

On the other hand, the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\max\{0,x\}\end{array}$$is continuous, in spite of the fact that $f^{-1}(\{0\})=(-\infty,0]$, which is infinite.

Comment: I see now that I made a mistake the theorem is speaking about the co-finite topology. I will edit my question.